# Tkinter change window title bar

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to change windows title bar in Tkinter. I used the following code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()


def motion(event):
    print(event.x, event.y, event.x_root, event.y_root)


def move_window(event):

    root.geometry('+{0}+{1}'.format(event.x_root, event.y_root))


root.overrideredirect(True)  # turns off title bar, geometry
root.geometry('400x100+200+200')  # set new geometry
root.update()

# make a frame for the title bar
title_bar = Frame(root, bg='white', relief='raised', bd=2)

# put a close button on the title bar
close_button = Button(title_bar, text='X', command=root.destroy)

# a canvas for the main area of the window
window = Canvas(root, bg='black')

# pack the widgets
title_bar.pack(expand=1, fill=X)
close_button.pack(side=RIGHT)
window.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH)

# bind title bar motion to the move window function
title_bar.bind('<B1-Motion>', move_window)
root.bind('<Motion>', motion)

root.mainloop()
```

But It's not working properly when I am dragging or changing the position of the window. How can it be fixed?

Comment: What does "not working properly" mean? What does it do that is different than what you expect?

Comment: it is unclear what you try to do and what result you expect.

Comment: When I am dragging the window using the mouse, then It is not dragging normally or on the correct position where I want to drag.

Answer (score 0):

In every other solution, the window was jumping to the mouse position. Here is a solution that doesn't do that:

```
import tkinter as tk

class TitleBar(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master, height=20, bg='blue')
        self.master = master
        self.old_x = None
        self.old_y = None
        self.pack(side='top', padx=0, pady=0, fill='x')
        self.title_bar()
        self.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.move_window)
        self.bind('<ButtonRelease>', self.on_release)

    def move_window(self, event):
        if self.old_x and self.old_y:
            geometry = self.master.geometry()
            position = geometry.split('+')[1:]
            x_position, y_position = map(int, position)
            self.master.geometry(f'+{x_position+(event.x-self.old_x)}+{y_position+(event.y-self.old_y)}')
        else:
            self.old_x = event.x
            self.old_y = event.y

    def on_release(self, event):
        self.old_x = None
        self.old_y = None

    def title_bar(self):
        self.title_ = tk.Label(self, text='Your title here', bg='blue')
        self.title_.pack(side='left')
        self.quit_button_ = tk.Button(self, text='x', command=self.quit_button_callback, width=2, height=1, bg='red')
        self.quit_button_.pack(side='right')

    def quit_button_callback(self):
        self.master.destroy()

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry('480x360+200+200')
        TitleBar(self)
        self.main_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.main_frame.pack(side='bottom', padx=4, pady=4)
        self.overrideredirect(True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```